# Closest Point on 2D Implicit Line

Tags: geometry

Consider the infinite line, $L$ in $2D$ consisting of all points $p$ such that $p.[0.3511 0.9263]= 6$. Find the point on the line closest to $(10, 20)$. Find the point on the line closest to $(4, 3)$. Find the distance from the line to both of these points.

Hi, I was reading the book $3D$ Maths Primer for Graphics and Game Development. The book mention about $2$ formulas but I don't know how to apply them.

$\text{Signed distance} = d-q.n$

$q' = q + (d-q.n)n$

for any point $q$, the point $q'$ that is the closest point on $L$ to $q$.

This is what I have tried,

Since the lines are parallel then the normal are the same so

$q' = q + (6 - q(0.3511 0.9263))(0.3511 0.9263)$

I'm stuck here.

Comment: Seen [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html)?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to link the given formula in solving this question but i can't solve it.

Comment: Can you please use math formatting for the formulas. And accept an answer as a solution soon.

Answer (score 2):

If a line is given by $\vec{p}\cdot\vec{n}=d$ where $\vec{p}=(x,y)$ is a point on the line, then $\vec{n}$ is the unit normal vector to the line (perpendicular direction) and $d$ is the minimum distance to the origin. For your case you have $ \vec{p}\cdot(0.3511,0.9263)=6 $, but unfortunately $\vec{n}$ is not a unit vector here. To make it a unit vector you have

$$ \vec{p}\cdot(0.3544,0.9351)=6.0569 $$

with $\vec{n}=(0.3544,0.9351)$ and $ d=6.0569 $. The distance between the point *P* and the closest point to the line is the perpendicular projection of the difference between *P* and *A* where is any point on the line. I choose the point *A* with coordinates $\vec{a}=\vec{n}\,d=(2.1467,5.6637)$ representing the closest point of the line to the origin. The distance of *P* with the line is $r=\vec{n}\cdot(\vec{p}-\vec{a})$ or

$$ r = \vec{n}\cdot\vec{p}-d $$

with $r = 16.189 $ for *P*=(10,20).

The point *P'* closest to the line is offset from *P* by $r$, with the equation $\vec{p}'=\vec{p}-\vec{n}\,r = \vec{p}-\vec{n}(\vec{n}\cdot\vec{p}-d) $, or

$$ \vec{p}' = \vec{p}-(\vec{n}\cdot\vec{p}-d)\vec{n} $$

with $\vec{p}'=(4.2621,4.8619)$

Here is the checks I did with [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/).

[image: Line & Point]

So proceed similarly with point *Q* = (4,3) to get *Q'* and the distance between *P'* and *Q'* as **0.415**

[image: Second Point]

Answer (score 0):

You've got a line $L:ax+by=c$ where $a,b,c$ are given.

You've got a point $P=(r,s)$.

You want the point $Q$ on $L$ closest to $P$. Let's call it $Q=(u,v)$.

You know $Q$ is on $L$, so $au+bv=c$.

You know the line from $P$ to $Q$ is perpendicular to $L$. Can you figure out the slope (EDIT: also known as the *gradient*) of the line from $P$ to $Q$ (slope of a line joining two given points)? Can you figure out the slope of $L$ (slope of a line, given an equation of the line)? Do you know the relation between the slopes of two perpendicular lines?

If you can answer all those questions, you get a second equation relating the two unknowns $u,v$. Can you solve a system of two equations in two unknowns?

Comment: HI, when you say slope do you mean the gradient? using y = mx + c?

Comment: When I say slope, I mean slope. But, yes, many people use gradient to mean what I mean when I say slope.